# Web Api Content response to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I am working with an api where I am trying to download a pdf file over a web request.

Currently, I am using postman to save the file by clicking "Send And Download":
[image]

This is working 100%.

After this I exported the code from Postman and made a console application and added the last 3 lines to make it look like this:
[image]

The Desired pdf has got 18 pages, when I run this I get the 18 pages pdf however all the content is missing. Here is a debug view of the "response.Content"

[image]

When I save the content to a txt file it looks something like this:

[image]

My question is, can anyone please help me on how I can take this response content and save the pdf on my end to look like the original pdf?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, here is the solution:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

var filePath2 = @"*filepath*\test.pdf";
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath2, response.RawBytes);
```

So what needed to happen is that the file save method had to change to "WriteAllBytes" instead of "WriteAllText" and then the "response.Content" had to change to "response.RawBytes"

If you change all of the content to Bytes the pdf can understand it instead of the former string conversion... Hope this helps someone else as well. :-)

Happy coding